# ASP.NET Giving error: Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, scriptmanager, report-viewer2010

I'm trying to display an RDL report using the `ReportViewer` control. I already managed to load my report with some help of SO. But now i'm facing another problem.

The report is loaded, because it shows all the parameter textfields of the report. But when i fill those in then no report results are shown. The exact same params **do** work when i view the report in my web browser through the ReportServer URL.

I think the problem is because it also displays this error on my ASP.NET page (where i have the ReportViewer control).

> Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to
>   allow scripts.

Which is weird, because every other javascript enabled site works perfectly fine for me. I believe this error is thrown because i have a `ScriptManager` in my ASP.NET page.

I have no idea how to fix this problem. Anyone any idea how to solve this problem?

---

### NOTE:

The error **does not** appear when i remove the `ReportViewer` control. I can also execute an `alert` in a `<script>` tag. So JS seems to be working.

---

This is what i have in my page:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>Report</h2
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
        Font-Size="8pt" Height="742px" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
        ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" 
        WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="907px">
        <ServerReport ReportPath="http://server.com/Product/Dashboards/Product_tool.rdl" 
            ReportServerUrl="http://server.com/ReportServer" />
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
</asp:Content>
```

And in my `PageLoad`:

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportCredentials("user", "pass");
ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: Can you post your page that has the scriptmanager control (or at least a portion of it)?

Comment: @unicron I added some code, is that what you want to see?

Comment: Yes.  Have you tried deploying your project to another server besides localhost?

Comment: @unicron Not yet, i'll try that next monday, since i'm not in town for the upcoming days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause for this is that the site is on an address that isn't trusted. Internet Explorer opens sites in zones, and it may have put your development address in an untrusted zone, which disables scripts by default. You can usually see an icon somewhere that indicates this and allows you to add the address to the trusted zone.

Look for an eye icon or a warning icon - depending on the version of Internet Explorer you are using.

You could also fire up another browser and see if it is any different.

Comment: Just tested it with Safari, same result. Any idea?

Comment: I guess the other possibility is that JavaScript is enabled, but there is an error stopping it from executing? Anything in the browser console?

Comment: No errors at all. Just tried it with Firefox and firebug aswell. I'm running it in a Windows Server 2008 R2 though. Can it be a security setting that doesn't allow `Javascript` in `localhost`?

Comment: Actually, i don't think that scripts are blocked on `localhost`. Because an `alert()` seems to be working fine in `<script> ` tags...

Comment: This is strange because as far as I can see, the message you are seeing is in a `<noscript>` tag - so the only thing that should cause this to display is JavaScript being disabled (or not supported).

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. Also when i wrap the `ReportViewer` and the `ScriptManager` in a `<div>` then i don't see the error. I'm not sure if that means the error is really gone. Because the report still doesn't show any data when i press on the 'view results` button. It does always show the Ajax `loading` popup though, which is JS based... I'm so clueless about this :(